# Application of Derivatives (Rolle's Theorem?)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, cubics, rolles-theorem

Let there be a cubic equation $f(x)=ax³+bx²+cx+d=0$, and the coefficients of the equation be related by $-a+b-c+d=3$ and $8a+4b+2c+d=6$. How can I show that the quadratic equation $3ax²+2bx+c-1$ has a root in $(-1,2)$?

I believe that if we apply Rolle's Theorem for the cubic and we show that $f(-1)=f(2)$ (already the cubic is continuous in $[-1,2]$ and differentiable in $(-1,2)$), we can prove that $f'(x)$ has a root in (-1,2).  But the given quadratic isn't exactly equal to f'(x).

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and use Rolle.

Because $g(-1)=g(2)=4.$

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was really silly of me to have not considered/spotted this.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

By [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), for some $x\in(-1, 2)$:
$$f(2)-f(-1)=(2-(-1))f'(x) \implies f'(x)=1$$

Comment: Thanks for the help!